# Conditional probability and expected value calculation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value

> A football team, LIBO, wins a match with probability 0.75 irrespective of its
>   opponents. What is the probability that the team wins 4 matches out of 5 matches?
>
> In a knockout tournament, LIBO faces a series of opponents until it loses to someone.
>   How many matches does LIBO expect to play before it gets eliminated from the
>   tournament?
>
> If LIBO is already in Quarter final, what is the probability that it's going to
>   play the Final and becomes Champion?

For the solution what i've assumed

(a)${5 \choose 4} (0.75)^4 (1-0.75)$

(b)$E[N] = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}i(0.75)^i(1-0.75)^{n-i}$

(c) $P(A|B) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$

But i'm not sure how to solve the (b) and (c) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (b),
$$E[N] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i P(N=i).$$
What is $P(N=i)$ (probability of playing $i$ matches before being eliminated)? They need to win $i-1$ matches and lose the last one.

For (c), you don't need conditional probability. They just need to win three matches (assuming it's a single-elimination tournament bracket).

Comment: i have edited my question just now, can you please explain more? i know to they need to win i-1 matches, but how should i calculate that?